# Use mean value theorem to prove $(1+x)^3 \ge (1+2x)$, where $x\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We know $(1+x)^3 \ge (1+3x) \ge (1+2x)$.
Also we take $f(x)=(1+x)^3$, we can prove $f'(x)=3(1+x)^2\ge (1+2x)$ But I don't have any idea how to use MVT for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: $x=1+t$ with $t\ge0$ becomes $t^3+6t^2+10t+5\ge0$ which is evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $$f(x)={(1+x)}^3-1-2x$$ By MVT there is some $c\in(1,x)$ $$f(x)-f(1)=(x-1)(3{(1+c)}^2-2)$$ but$$3{(1+c)}^2-2\ge 0$$  $$\to f(x)\ge f(1)>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'(x)\geqslant12\geqslant2$ if $x\geqslant1$. So, if $x\geqslant1$, then, by the mean value theorem,$$f(x)-f(1)\geqslant2(x-1)(\iff f(x)\geqslant2x-2+8\geqslant2x+1).$$